# Django: Passing model object values through url

Tags: django, django-urls, django-templates

I'm having problems with passing model object values through a URL pattern. The URL:

```
url(r'^cities/(?P<city>\w+)/$', 'city_firm', name='city_firm'),
```

In the template (from the index page) I have:

```
<a href="{% url city_firm city %}">{{ city }}</a>
```

This is in a `for` loop.

The related view is:

```
def city_firm(request, city):
    city1 = Cities.objects.get(city=city)
    cityf = city1.Firms.all()
    return render_to_response('cityfirm.html', {'cityf': cityf})
```

The two models (`Cities`, `Firms`) are in a many to many relationship.
I keep getting `TemplateSyntaxError` at index (`NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'city_firm' with arguments '(<Cities: >,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found`). In the template link tag I tried: `{% url city_firm city=city %}`, `{% url city_firm city=cities.city %}`. Nothing changed. The `urlconf` part seems right. The problem seems to be in the template. Maybe there is an issue with the string values of the object as they aren't in English. But I took several precautions to prevent this. There is maybe something wrong with the view but the error says template. Any ideas?

**Solution**:
Thanks everyone! Finally I figured it out. The problem was simple: I was trying to send object attribute names through the url, that had non-English characters and spaces. To fix it, I had to edit my models.

Comment: try to send `city.city` instead of `city`

Comment: If you solved your own issue, supply it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you can't pass an object in a URL, you can only pass characters. So you need to put the part of the `city` object that contains the text you want to be in the URL - in your case, it appears to be an attribute also called `city`, which is what you use to in the lookup to get the object in the view. So it should be:

```
<a href="{% url city_firm city.city %}">{{ city }}</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's indeed noway to pass an object so that the url resolves expected keywords from that object. I can't find any app doing that in Django.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `name` means what you think it does - remove that and read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

As far as the error... the `NoReverseMatch` is telling you that it's not seeing any arguments. Remember that nonexisting template variables expand to "". Make sure `city` is in context when you're running that code - maybe post the `for` in the template?